# How to mock complex query criteria using mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito, criteria

I'm writing a junit test case for a method in the data access layer, how  to stub/verify a complex query using mockito?

checked the following links on how to stub a complex query: 
- https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-queries-tutorial/
- https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/933

none of them match my case, and the documentation does not say much about it 
https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/index.html?org/mockito/Mockito.html

Actual code :

```
public List<Content> getContentByParams(String entity, String channelId, String sectionId,
            Integer limit, String[] retrievedFields) {

    Query<Content> query = this.createQuery();

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(channelId) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(sectionId)) {


        query.and(query.criteria("name").equalIgnoreCase(entity),

        query.criteria("channel").equal(channelId),

        query.criteria("section").equal(sectionId));
            System.out.println("after===============");
    }
    if (retrievedFields != null && retrievedFields.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("retrieved fields");
            for (String field : retrievedFields) {
                query.project(field, true);
            }
        }

        if (limit == null) {
            limit = 4;
        }

        FindOptions findOptions = new FindOptions().limit(limit);

        return query.asList(findOptions);
}
```

Test case :

```
public void getContentByEntitiesAndPrimaryChannelSection() {
        FieldEnd<Criteria> mockFieldEndEntity = mock(FieldEnd.class);
        FieldEnd<Criteria> mockFieldEndChannel = mock(FieldEnd.class);
        FieldEnd<Criteria> mockFieldEndSection = mock(FieldEnd.class);

        // doReturn(mockFieldEndEntity).when(query).criteria("name");
        // doReturn(mockFieldEndChannel).when(query).criteria("channel");
        // doReturn(mockFieldEndSection).when(query).criteria("section");

        contentDAO.getContentByParams(entity, "channel_3", "section_3", 10, mockFields);

        for (String field : mockFields) {
            verify(query).project(field, true);
        }


        ArgumentCaptor<FindOptions> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(FindOptions.class);

        verify(query).asList(argument.capture());

        FindOptions findOptions = argument.getValue();
        assertEquals(10, findOptions.getLimit());

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(MongoQueryUtil.class, times(1));
    }
```

I am unsure on how to add a test for the query creation part with the test current status it passes but it is not testing the query creation.
any help will be appreciated or if there is a documentation for it somewhere.

Comment: Do you want to test the SQL statement generated by hibernate criteria ?

Comment: Why are you not evaluating the actual output of the getContentByParams function?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande yes that exactly what I want to

Comment: @DanielCampos will I tried doing so using verify but I end up with a compilation error saying that .and is not compatible for this method and I don't know how to do it

Comment: @aishaalkhateeb It is a bad idea to test the sql generated by hibernate because hibernate is supposed to provide you an abstraction over the underlying db. So if you test db specific sql you might as well use raw sql statements instead of criteria.
I'd suggest you should consider what DanielCampos is suggesting. Compare the output returned by the function

Comment: Have you tried saving the output value from contentDAO.getContentByParams(...) in one variable and assert that the output is the same that you expect?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I suppose that what we wants to do is to test that the logic that he implemented for the query creation is working, that's why I said to create manually the expected SQL statement and then assert that the one that you create is the same that the one that the method has as output.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande then how do you suggest I do it ?

Comment: @DanielCampos okay I tried that and it passes but How to verify that the query was called ?

Comment: You don't have to, the purpose of Hibernate is that it gives to you the abstraction layer, you shouldn't try to test it.

Comment: insert test data in DB/ mock DB. Call `getContentByParams` with different filter combinations and this should return the results. compare the result with test data

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande yup that works. thank you both AnkitDeshpande & DanielCampos. one final question where can I find docs on this topic ?

Comment: @aishaalkhateeb docs about unit testing ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande unit testing complex query criteria/ hibernate